# Printing the 2 list together

Tags: java, list, class

I am trying to print StudentList from the class Student using the University class

Code for UniversityClass:

```
public class University {
    Unit[] units = new Unit[3];
    Student student1;
    Student student2;
    Student student3;


public void printStatus() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java University");
    System.out.println();
    createUnits();
    displayUnits();
    System.out.println("Thank you for using Java University");
}
public void createUnits() {
    units[0] = new Unit("FIT1234", "Advance Bogosorts");
    student1 = new Student(1234, "Mark", "Stevens");
    student2 = new Student(5678, "Steven", "Perry");
    units[1] = new Unit("FIT2345", "Java Programming");
    student3 = new Student(9012, "Cooper", "Smith");
    units[2] = new Unit("FIT3456"," Java Fundamentals");

}

public void displayUnits() {
    for (int i =0; i<units.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(units[i].description());
    System.out.println(student1.description());
    System.out.println(student2.description());
    System.out.println(student3.description());
        }
    }

}
```

Code for StudentList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Unit {
    private String unitcode;
    private String unitname;


public Unit(String x,String y) {
    unitcode = x;
    unitname = y;

}
private final List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean addStudents(Student newStudents){
        studentList.add(newStudents);
        return true;

}

public String description() {
        return unitcode + " " + unitname;
        }


}
```

The output I get

```
    Welcome to Java University
    FIT1234 Advance Bogosorts
    1234 Mark Stevens
    5678 Steven Perry
    9012 Cooper Smith
    FIT2345 Java Programming
    1234 Mark Stevens
    5678 Steven Perry
    9012 Cooper Smith
    FIT3456  Java Fundamentals
    1234 Mark Stevens
    5678 Steven Perry
    9012 Cooper Smith
    Thank you for using Java University
```

The output I want

```
Welcome to Java University
FIT1234 Advance Bogosorts
1234 Mark Stevens
5678 Steven Perry
FIT2345 Java Programming
9012 Cooper Smith
FIT3456  Java Fundamentals
Thank you for using Java University
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I made a studentlist and added each student into the list but I don't get the right output. Am I suppose to add the students into the Unit List instead so that each student is enrolled into a unit or am I printing in the wrong order? Can anyone please offer me a solution?

Comment: Do you ever `addStudents` to the units you create?

Comment: Where is `main()`? Also, you clearly know how to use an array for the `Unit`s. You should do the same for `Student`s as well. Names like `student1`, `student2`, and `student3` indicate that you should use an array (or a `List`) instead of variables that end in a number.

Comment: My main() is in another class. There's actually 2 more classes but I was thinking posting all of the classes would be a bit too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the method `displayUnits` to print only the students registered on a given course:

```
public void displayUnits() {
    for (int i =0; i<units.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(units[i].description());

        for (Student student: units[i].getStudents()) {
            System.out.println(student.description());
        }  
    }
}
```

To achieve this, you will need to

**1)** Add a getter method in the class `Unit`:

```
public class Unit {
   ...
   private final List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<Student> getStudents() {
      return studentList;
   }
   ...
}
```

**2)** Populate the list of students in your `Unit` objects - and likely get rid of the instance variables `student1`, `student2` and `student3`:

```
public void createUnits() {
    units[0] = new Unit("FIT1234", "Advance Bogosorts");
    units[0].studentList.add(new Student(1234, "Mark", "Stevens"));
    units[0].studentList.add(new Student(5678, "Steven", "Perry"));

    units[1] = new Unit("FIT2345", "Java Programming");
    units[1].studentList.add(new Student(9012, "Cooper", "Smith"));

    units[2] = new Unit("FIT3456"," Java Fundamentals");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between units and students, so I think you need to add students to the units as well.....